returning multiple values ​when running plumber API
I created xgboost model with caret library in R. And when I run this model in plumber, in Swagger response body apperance all predictions for database. I just want a prediction. The one that corresponds to the inserted categories of the model variables. Below example of my API
model <- readRDS('model_xgb.rds')

    #\* param var1
    #\* param var2
    #\* param var3
    #\* param var4
    #\* get/prediction
    
    function(var1,var2,var3,var4)
    
    {
    data<-
    tibble(
    var1=as.factor(var1),
    var2=as.factor(var2),
    var3=as.factor(var3),
    var4=as.factor(var4)
    )
    
    predict(model,new_data=data, type='prob') %>% pluck(1)
    
    }

Plumber is returning:
[
{"0":0.9152,
"1":0.0848
},
{"0":0.5379,
"1":0.4621
},
{"0":0.9912,
"1":0.0088
}
.
.
.
]

I want just one result
